# Cannot import name 'KEY_RIGHT' from 'curses'

Tags: python, curses

[It shows that pycharm is creating importerror of curses why?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k7lU.jpg)

```
"C:\Users\Adarsh kumar gupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" "C:/Documents/python programs/untitled2june/snkgame.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Documents/python programs/untitled2june/snkgame.py", line 5, in <module>
    from curses import KEY_RIGHT, KEY_LEFT, KEY_UP, KEY_DOWN
ImportError: cannot import name 'KEY_RIGHT' from 'curses' (C:\Users\Adarsh kumar gupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\curses\__init__.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Have you properly installed curses package ? Because trying all the three import statements in my local machine is not giving me any error.

Comment: Yes., i have installed  window-curses in my pycharm.

Comment: @Adarshgupta It is "windows-curses" with an s at the end of window.